# Make modal with clickable background with no JavaScript

Tags: css, background, modal-dialog

I want to make a simple modal that does not use JavaScript but has the ability to be able to click on the background to close the modal.

I found this demo which I like except is there a way to not have the address bar contain the id of the modal? Or is there another trick that can be done to make a modal with a clickable background without JavaScript.

https://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/222/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need (there is a live example below).

But my solution has one limitation: there can be only one modal window - no more!

Original idea: https://www.cssscript.com/minimal-overlay-modal-pure-css/

```css
.js-btn:focus ~ #modal, .js-btn:active ~ #modal,
#modal:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

body {
  font-family: serif;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: opacity 200ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms;
}
.overlay .cancel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: default;
}
.modal {
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

button {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s box-shadow ease;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}

button:hover { box-shadow: 0 12px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); }
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Puse CSS Modal with overlay</h1>

<button class="js-btn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="modal" class="overlay" tabindex="-1">
  <a class="cancel" href="#"></a>
  <div class="modal">
    <h2>This is Modal Overlay 1</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Click outside the modal to close.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to not have the id placed in the address bar when you open or close a modal?

Comment: Try my solution with live example - just click "Run code snippet"

Answer (score 0):

You can do some pretty cool stuff with the [checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/).

Basically you (ab)use [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) and their ability to check/uncheck a [checkbox input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) remotely.   When the checkbox is active you can use the [checked psuedo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) (`:checked`) along with the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (`+`) to style the next element and all of it's children, in this case the modal and the lightbox effect.  You can also use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~`) to get the same effect, but I find scoping with the adjacent one easier.

To make the modal openable and closable, I used two labels. the first opens the modal (check the checkbox) and the other to close it (uncheck the checkbox).  You could use more labels to make a close button, or other ways to open the modal, etc.  Just make sure that the `for` attribute matches the `id` of the checkbox.

All the setup that's really needed is the checkbox input, the two labels, your trigger (wrapped by one label), a container for your modal (for positioning - I also used it for the darker background), and your modal itself.  Just make sure that the modal has a higher z-index (or on its own stacking context) than the closing label, otherwise clicking the modal will close itself.

I left the checkbox visible, so you can get a better idea on how this works.

```css
.lightbox {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000A;
}

#modal-toggle:checked + .lightbox {
  display: flex;
}

.lightbox > label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.modal {
  z-index: 1;
}

/* For looks only */

.modal-trigger {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.modal,
.modal-trigger {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.modal *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #DDD;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#modal-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Pure CSS Modal - Checkbox Hack</h1>

<label class="modal-trigger" for="modal-toggle">
    Open Modal
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="modal-toggle">
<div class="lightbox">
  <label for="modal-toggle"></label>
  <div class="modal">
    <h3>This is a Modal</h3>
    <p>Click outside the modal to close</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also made a [codepen with multiple modals](https://codepen.io/DSMann/pen/BaoGBaV) on the same page.